# Running Meteor mobile app on physical Android device

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm having an hard time trying to run my Meteor app on my Android device (LG G2).
I googled for answer and didn't find anything like what I encounter. I followed the instuction and everything went fine, added the Android platform to my project and ran it with `meteor run android-device`. The device LG G2 is plugged with a USB cable to the machine I'm building and running the app with, and the device has USB debugging enabled. Everything seem to be fine, my terminal indicates:

```
Started proxy.
Started app on Android Device.
I20150530-16:38:11.280(3)? - waiting for device -
Started MongoDB.
Started your app.

App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

No error indication, nothing suspicous, but the app doesn't come up on the device. Nothing happens. Anyone has a clue? I tried to give my own IP and port to the command without a change.

Comment: Does `adb devices` command lists your device ?

Comment: are you running linux/ubuntu? If so, then quite possibly you'll need to add a udev rule, see Step 3 in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up

Comment: @ChristianFritz Thank you! I'm using Ubuntu and followed the instructions, helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll list what I've done to solve it, because it's a mix of all the solutions I got here.

I'm using Ubuntu, and LG G2 as device.

- I created the `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules.` file with
  `SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="1004", GROUP="plugdev"` inside. (Detailed instructions here on step 3: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up, thank you @ChristianFritz). Pay attention that "1004" is the vendor
  ID of LG.
- I realised that for some reason I didn't have the ADB on my machine so I couldn't use adb devices and connect with my device. I followed this guide:
  http://lifehacker.com/the-easiest-way-to-install-androids-adb-and-fastboot-to-1586992378 to install the missing ADB (linux section).
- I got an error: `adb server is out of date. killing...` which terminated connection between the device to the machine, but after following @yoh advice, I changed my USB connection from MTP to PTP and tried again. This time worked.

Managed to run my app successfully on physical LG G2 after those steps using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the USB connexion on your android device as "camera". Whith my s4 mini I had the same symptoms and that was the solution.

Comment: Had no "camera" option, but seems PTP instead of MTP did the job. Thanks!

Comment: yes, it says "appareil photo (PTP)" on my phone. "appareil photo" is "camera" in french.